# Induction proof: $\det(M) = \prod_{1 \le j \le n} (x_j - x_i)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

Following problem:

> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a Field and
>
> $M = \begin{pmatrix}    1 & x_1 & \ldots & x_1^{n-1} \\    \vdots &
>  \vdots & & \vdots \\    1 & x_n & \ldots  & x_n^{n-1} \end{pmatrix} \in
>  Mat(n, \mathbb{K})$
>
> Proove with induction that: $$\det(M) = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} (x_j -
>  x_i)$$

Unfortunately I am totally lost here. I have confirmed $n = 1$ and for the rest I got the following:

$$\prod_{1 \le i < j \le n + 1} (x_j - x_i) = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} (x_j - x_i) \prod_{1 \le i < n + 1} (x_{n+1} - x_i) = \det(M_n) \prod_{1 \le i < n + 1} (x_{n+1} - x_i) $$

From there on I don't know how to continue.

Any ideas? :S Thanks!

Comment: @Winther You are right. My bad I will fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Also the formula you write is not correct. $(x_{n+1}-x_n)$  should be $(x_{n+1} - x_1)(x_{n+1} - x_2)\ldots (x_{n+1} - x_n)$. Anyway you cannot prove it (just) this way. You need to use what the determinant of the matrix $M_{n+1}$ is and relate this to the determinant of $M_{n}$. btw the matrix you have is known as the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Comment: @Winther Ah - I see. Sure totally overlooked the fact that there are too product-signs involved... thanks. I'll fix it, too.

Comment: Did you try subtracting row $R_{n+1}$ from each row $R_i$, $1 \le i \le n$, then expanding through the first column?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735883/calculate-determinant-of-vandermonde-using-specified-steps) has a step by step way to prove it. If you manage to get to point d) then you can apply induction to arrive at the result.