# Proving linear independence of $e^{a_it}, i=1,...,n$

Tags: determinant, wronskian

As the title states, I'm trying to prove that a system $e^{a_1t},e^{a_2t},...,e^{a_nt}$ defined on $C[a,b]$ is linearly independent if $a_i$ are distinct ($a_i\neq a_j$ if $i\neq j$). So I put these functions into Wronskian and try to evaluate value of the determinant.
$$
W\left[e^{\alpha_it}\right](t) =
\begin{vmatrix}
e^{\alpha_1t} & \cdots & e^{\alpha_n t}\\
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\alpha_1^{n-1}e^{\alpha_1t} & \cdots & \alpha_n^{n-1}e^{\alpha_nt}
\end{vmatrix}
= \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i t\right)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\alpha_1^{n-1} & \cdots & \alpha_n^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
$$
However, I don't know how to prove the determinant is not zero. I have tried method of mathematical induction but I can't find a clear relationship for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$. So, how to prove that  the determinant has a non-zero value?

Comment: The determinant you have is that of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). It would suffice to note that this determinant is non-zero when the $a_i$ are distinct.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735883/calculate-determinant-of-vandermonde-using-specified-steps.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arrived at the transpose of the famous [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with the determinant
$$
\det M = \prod_{1\le i < j \le 1} (\alpha_j - \alpha_i),
$$
which is nonzero iff the $\alpha_i$ are distinct.

The proof is in the linked Wiki article.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.